# Showing just one link in a table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to show just one link in a table row even when there are more than one group(@existing_groups_ids). But now, my system shows two links in a table row when there are two groups. It may have three links in a table row when there are three groups. Could you tell me how to modify my code?

☆index_controller

```
def index
@keyword = params[:keyword]
 if @keyword.present?
   Amazon::Ecs.debug = true
   res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search(params[:keyword], 
      :search_index => 'All', :response_group => 'Medium')
   @items = res.items
  search_isbns = @items.map{ |isbns| isbns.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN')}
  @existing_groups_isbns = Group.select(:isbn).where(:isbn => search_isbns).map(&:isbn)
  @existing_groups_ids = Group.where(:isbn => search_isbns).map{|g| g.id}
 end
end
```

☆index.html.erb(index_controller)

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
   <th>image</th>
   <th>タイトル</th>
   <th>著者</th>
   <th>出版年</th>
   <th>出版社</th>
   <th>page</th>
   <th>リンク</th>
 </tr>
<% if @items.present? %>
 <% @items.each do |i| %>
   <tr>
     <td> <%= link_to image_tag(i.get('SmallImage/URL'), {:style => 'border: none;'}), i.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
  <td> <%= link_to i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'), i.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
  <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Author') %></td>
  <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate')%></td>
  <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher') %></td>
  <td> <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages')%></td>
  <td>
    <% if @existing_groups_isbns.include? i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN') %>
        <% @existing_groups_ids.each do |id| %>
          <%= link_to '既存グループへ', group_path(id) %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
     <%= link_to '新規作成', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'new', :name => i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'),:author => i.get('ItemAttributes/Author'), :publish => i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher'), :published => i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate'), :isbn => i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN'), :page => i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages'), :imageurl=>i.get('MediumImage/URL')} ,class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%>
    <% end %> <!-- if @existing_groups_isbns-->     
  </td>
</tr>
 <% end %><!-- each do-->
<% else %>
  見つかりませんでした。
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
```

and

```
<% @existing_groups_ids.each do |id| %>
  <%= link_to '既存グループへ', group_path(id) %>
<% end %>
```

with:

```
<% @items.each_with_index do |i, index| %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to '既存グループへ', group_path(@existing_groups_ids[index]) %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.NARKOZ. I revised my codes in line with your advice. But it shows only group/2 in every existing row. what I would like to realize is like group/2 for the row of existing group2 as well as group/3 for the row of existing group3.

Comment: I don't understand, but updated answer. Hope this will help `:)`

Comment: Thank you again. it worked on index.html.erb but brought an error message when I searched a book with Amazon API.  ActionController::RoutingError at /index/index
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :id=>nil}. I checked the log. Some numbers were put in @existing_groups_ids as an array. On the other hand, @existing_groups_ids[index] was nill.

Comment: use `group_path(@existing_groups_ids[index]) unless group_path(@existing_groups_ids[index]).blank?`

Comment: Many thanks. I tried the modification. But it doesn't cure the error.